# How to change Kendo autocomplete filed slimier as Angular material input fields?

Tags: angular, kendo-autocomplete

**I want to change the kendo autocomplete filed the same as the angular material inputs.**

the kendo UI autocomplete field is like below

[image]

I want to change above kendo UI autocomplete field is like below

[image]

the HTML for the kendo UI autocomplete field is like below

```
<div class="example-wrapper">
    <kendo-autocomplete [data]="listItems" [placeholder]="'e.g. Andorra'">
    </kendo-autocomplete>
</div>
```

the HTML for the material UI is like below.

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Groups"  matInput [formControl]="queryField">
</mat-form-field>
```

is it possible to do that?

Comment: Have you used material theme of kendo?

Comment: you can use angular material auto complete 
   --------- https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using kendo, you can wrap kendo components in material design.

you can install `kendo-theme-material` in your project.

```
npm install --save @progress/kendo-theme-material
```

And in your `angular.json` file add path to `kendo-theme-material`.

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "styles": [
        "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-material/dist/all.css"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

It will convert all your kendo components in material design.